# What is phpBB? Is it something like a plugin which I can use in Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, themes

I did some research on phpBB. It says it's a forum plugin, but it is nowhere mentioned that this plugin can be used in Wordpress. Then I saw [this forum](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/phpbb-vs-wordpress-forum-plugin.1666322/) where phpBB and Wordpress plugins are compared (still look like both are different).

I saw a couple of questions regarding phpBB in Wordpress Development StackExchange, but none of them answer my question.

So, if I buy [this theme](https://themeforest.net/item/hawiki-forum-theme/6879435), then can I use it in Wordpress? If no, then which platform can be used to edit the theme? Will be code be PHP, or can I use HTML and CSS?

Sorry for too many questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> phpBB is a free flat-forum bulletin board software solution
>
> https://www.phpbb.com/

I am not sure where had you got “plugin” bit from, phpBB is most definitely *standalone software*, which does not require or rely on WordPress.

If you see the mentions of the two together it typically refers to some form of integration, such as sharing login details for users between them.

Theme you link to is specifically *phpBB theme*, you should check their documentation for expectations on editing it.